# No bootable medium found! error when loading custom OS

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, boot, bootloader

I am trying to load a very small, simple operating system I made in Virtualbox with a virtual floppy image, and I get the "`FATAL: No bootable medium found!`" error. The OS itself is just supposed to be something to test the bootloader, and all it does is write a '7' to the screen. I wrote the bootloader/OS with FASM, made an image file (.img) with the CMD copy command (C:>copy /b bootloader.bin bootload.img), loaded it into the virtual floppy and when I try to boot it up, it won't load. Why is this? Scanning the logs doesn't help me, because they didn't tell me where Virtualbox was looking for the image file, at least from what I could understand of them. Looking over several SO threads turns up a lot of good information, but all of it for Linux, which I am currently not running. The code for the bootloader is located here: http://pastebin.com/Qnf8DBgQ

**Short version:** Made an OS, loaded it into Virtualbox, `FATAL: No bootable medium found!` Why?

I'm using this particular bootloader configuration because I'm following an OS dev video series on YouTube and I want to be able actually to follow it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOmPPmINoUs

Comment: "loaded it into the floppy controller"?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "virtual floppy." Edited.

Answer (score 0):

read about first floppy sector (first 512 bytes) - the BIOS looks for so called bootsector, loads it into memory and jumps to it. for example, find the bootable fdd image on the net and peek into that first sector

UPD: http://www.ata-atapi.com/hiwdos.html